# How can I instantiate a bean in spring using an existing object as a constructor argument

Tags: java, spring, interface, javabeans

I have an existing object, actually a socket, and I want that socket to be an instance variable of a bean that I create, a user session.

But if I get the user session from the applicationContext as a bean, how do I specify that I want its 'socket' property to be created using the existing socket?

Of course, I could just have a setSocket method on the user session bean, and call setSocket(socket) after I create the userSession bean. But that messes up my interfaces, because the actual class is 'UserSessionImpl', and it implements 'UserSession'. The socket is an implementation detail, so I don't want to have a 'setSocket' method a part of the UserSession interface.

I feel like I'm missing something.. Very grateful for your help!

EDIT: Posting relevant portions of the code.

So I have a piece of code that returns a socket like this:

```
while (true) {
    Socket socket = server.accept();
    UserSession userSession = (UserSession)applicationContext.getBean("userSession");

    // Without spring I would do this
    //UserSession userSession = new UserSessionImpl(socket);
    executorService.execute(userSession);
}
```

My spring applicationContext in nothing exciting - I just have

```
<bean id="userSession" class="server.UserSessionImpl" scope="prototype"></bean>
```

EDIT2: Can the downvoter explain the downvote? Seems like I asked a reasonable, useful question..?

Comment: Can you post some code or part of your `spring.xml` file?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, answering my own question here, but I think that I could:

- Define a socket bean, so that each user session gets created with its own socket bean
- Then I can set the socket property of the socket bean

That way, I don't have to create a method in the interface of UserSession that says 'setSocket' which is an implementation detail. Instead, I have a Socket interface, with a method 'setSocket' which makes much more sense. I think that should work. I'll post back..

EDIT: No, that doesn't work, because I still have to have a 'getSocket' method in the UserSession interface that I use to get the socket bean so I can set its socket. Hmm.